# How to set base url for Angular application

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have an Angular application as generated by JHipster. By default, it runs on the root `/` url, and redirects to `/#/`. Is there a way to override it to something else?

**edit**

Sorry, I have to rephrase my question, as it is misinterpreted in all answers below. I want to land my JHipster generated Angular application on something other than `/`, eg `/crud/`. The purpose is to serve some non-Angular content on `/`. How can I move the entire application from `/` to `/crud/`? And still have `/` served by a static `index.html` file?

Comment: isn't there a property in angular.json? `root` alternatively you can always create a property in the environment.json and pass it on the solution as a constant to build your urls

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Better to do it when you build project. Like this:

```
ng build --prod --base-href=/test/
```

Comment: This works especially well if, for example, you want to develop locally with the base href as the site root but want the base href to be something different when it is formally built and deployed to a server.

Comment: Please note, that both slashes are necessary in the `/test/`- I missed one and struggled for a while to find the reason.

Comment: @eddyP23 you saved my day!... ending slash fixes the issue. i almost gave on this issue. angular doc doesn't say anything important.

Comment: can set --base-href with some params too?

Answer (score 7):

You can modify it using `<base href="/">` in `src/index.html` file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SiteFrontend</title>
    <base href="/test">   //<------ this line

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a great tip.  I was able to do it in the container on the fly to verify the fix works, without having to modify the image first.

Answer (score 5):

Please follow these following steps:

1. Set `useHash: false` in `app-routing-module.ts`
2. In `index.html`, change `<base href="./" />` to  `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng build --prod --base-href=/test` and not `ng build --prod --base-href=/test/` because that way I won't load the images

Answer (score 1):

Below steps are for setting base url to /crud in production only which has worked for me

1. in `webpack.prod.js` add the following in plugins section:

   ```
   new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/crud' })
   ```
2. in `webpack.prod.js` in the output section add:

   ```
   publicPath: '/crud/',
   ```

On executing `npm run build` the index.html will prefix baseHref with '/crud' and also add prefix 'crud' to all the css and urls.